# How to get one parent object with a child nested array with association while using 'include' option to query in 'Sequelize'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have model Arhive

```
      const Archive = sequelize.define('Archive', {
date: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {});
Archive.associate = function(models) {
Archive.hasMany(models.Video, {
  foreignKey: 'ArchiveId',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  as: 'video'
});
Archive.hasMany(models.Photo, {
  foreignKey: 'ArchiveId',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});


};
 return Archive;
};
```

and model Video

```
  const Video = sequelize.define('Video', {
link: DataTypes.STRING,
pick: DataTypes.STRING,
date: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {});
Video.associate = function(models) {
Video.belongsTo(models.Archive, {
  foreignKey: 'ArchiveId',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',

});

// associations can be defined here
};
return Video;
```

I do a search

```
    models.Archive.findAll({
raw:true,
  attributes: ['id'],
include: [{// Notice `include` takes an ARRAY
  model: models.Video,
  as:'video',
  required:true,
  attributes: ['id'],
}]
})
.then(archive => console.log(archive))
.catch(console.error)
```

I get unexpected

```
[ { id: 1, 'video.id': 1 }, { id: 1, 'video.id': 2 } ]
```

How to get one parent object with a child nested array ?

> An example of the object to get

`[ { id: 1, video[id:1,id:2] } ]`
Is it possible to get a similar result with Sequelize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is remove `raw:true` from your query.

```
models.Archive.findAll({
    // raw: true, // <------- REMOVE THIS
    attributes: ['id'],
    include: [{ // Notice `include` takes an ARRAY
        model: models.Video,
        as: 'video',
        required: true,
        attributes: ['id'],
    }]
})
.then(archive => console.log(archive))
.catch(console.error)
```

It generates this kind of output while using it for nested levels with `raw:true`.